# Baking clean normals onto hard edges?

Tags: modeling, normals, texture-baking, normal-map

Trying to bake a beveled edge onto a hard edge with clean normals?

I keep getting these faint dotted lines (left) which causes pixelated shadows when applying the normal map to the low poly object.
[image]

Oppose to these ones where the edges are hard and clean.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well after looking closely I've found you need to make sure the rays align properly to bake a clean beveled edge.

Ive turned on 'display normals'. To give a better idea of how the rays need to be aligned with the lower poly model. This is specifically for baking in beveled edges.

[image]